# "sh: fork: retry: no child processes" issue in C

Tags: c

So this is my C program which will take in 3 user inputted numbers and output the sum. However, I have a problem regarding this when it was compiled :

```
sh: fork: retry: no child processes.
```

I'm a beginner in the C language, only used C#, what is the problem with my code? I used codinground.com to compile and execute by the way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int a,b,c;

    int sum;

    printf("Enter the first integer\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &a);

    printf("Enter the second integer\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &b);

    printf("Enter the third integer\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &c);

    sum = a + b + c;
    printf("The sum of those numbers is: %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you really write `(hash) include stdio.h` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: @mch No, when I tried to write copy the code here #include just made the word 'include' bold and I couldn't type in <stdio.h> as well :/

Comment: It seems to work: http://ideone.com/GZtONN

Comment: This code should work fine. What did you use to compile?

Comment: @szmonoloza   codinground.com seems to be some default/generic wordpress site, but if you are saying you posted your code to some online compiler service and it gave you the `sh: fork: retry: no child processes.` error, it means that web site is not working properly/overloaded/screwd up etc. and you should find some other way to compile and run your code.

Comment: @nos I'll give some other site a go. Know any good examples? And thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

The machine where you are compiling might be running low on resources
Try stopping some processes to get some memory freed and then try compilation again

Answer (score 1):

The message

> > sh: fork: retry: no child processes.

is emitted by the *shell*, `sh`.  This almost surely indicates that an attempt is being made to execute your C source code as a shell script or other interpreted script.  Your code is *not* a valid shell script, and it has no interpreter line (nor is there likely to be a viable interpreter anyway; see below), so this fails.

In principle, C source code could be run in an interpreter, like a script.  In practice, it is almost always compiled to a binary executable, and the executable then run.  Though the details vary, this is not inherently different from the C# case with which you are familiar.

I have no idea what you did at condinground.com to try to make it compile and run your program. I don't even see anything plausible to *try*, and it's unclear what would make you think that site provides any such service.  Ideally, you would get a C compiler that you can run locally, to produce an executable that you can also run locally -- there are good ones available for free.  If you insist on an online service, however, then you could consider [ideone](https://ideone.com).